# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток.

```
parser.add_argument('-f’, "--File", action="store", help="Файл для проверки")
```

В данной строке выбивает следующую ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, что не так. Пытался поиграться с кавычками, не то. Других идей, если честно, нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде ошибка/опечатка - не закрыта первая одинарная кавычка, а вместо этого открыта еще одна другого типа. Исправленый код:

```
parser.add_argument('-f', "--File", action="store", help="Файл для проверки")
```

Comment: Тьфу ты, такую глупость не заметил. Спасибо большое за помощь :3

Comment: примите ответ, нажав зеленую галочку слева от ответа